# Stock chart widget

Tags: android, finance, widget

I'd like a widget that can display the graph of recent prices (say over the past week) for a stock. It should be:

- Free (and no in-app purchases for essential functionality)
- Not show ads in the widget
- No excessive permissions
- Does not require me to make an account, or connect my existing account to it
- Can show individual stocks, as well as indices
- Non-ugly design
- Open source preferred
- Has a widget that can show charts, not just ticker

Is there such a thing?